# Property 'ctx' does not exist on type 'Props1'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js13

Good morning, I'm trying to update the types for this NextJS 13 client app.
I'm having some issues as I'm kinda new to Typescript
I would appreciate your help on identifying what am I doing wrong here please

The following code is working fine as is but yet Type script is complaining about the ctx

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { NextPageContext } from "next";
import buildClient from "../api/build-client";
import Header from "../components/header";
import { User } from "../types/types";
import { Component } from "react";

interface Props extends AppProps {
  currentUser: User;
}

interface Props1 extends NextPageContext {
  Component: any;
}

const AppComponent = ({ Component, pageProps, currentUser }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header currentUser={currentUser} />
      <div className="container">
        <Component
          currentUser={currentUser}
          {...pageProps}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

AppComponent.getInitialProps = async (appContext: Props1) => {
  const client = buildClient(appContext.ctx);
  const { data } = await client.get("/api/users/currentuser");
 
  let pageProps = {};
  if (appContext.Component.getInitialProps) {
    pageProps = await appContext.Component.getInitialProps(
      appContext.ctx,
      client,
      data.currentUser
    );
  }

  return {
    pageProps,
    ...data,
  };
};

export default AppComponent;
```

The error I'm getting at the moment is:

> Property 'ctx' does not exist on type 'Props1'

I'm not really sure how to resolve this issue despite the code works and no issues apparently in the app itself I'm concerned about this type issue.

Also the fact I added Component to type any doesn't seem like a good idea to me but yes it removes the error and I can do the same for ctx but seems a bit dodgy to me!

Any idea how to fix please? Thanks

When I added the fix recommended by Max on first answer it actually fixed the issue with ctx & component but now I got a new issue after the fix regarding "Expected 1 arguments, but got 3"

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { NextComponentType, NextPageContext } from "next";
import buildClient from "../api/build-client";
import Header from "../components/header";
import { User } from "../types/types";

interface Props extends AppProps {
  currentUser: User;
}

export type AppContextType = {
  Component: NextComponentType<NextPageContext>;
  ctx: NextPageContext;
};

const AppComponent = ({ Component, pageProps, currentUser }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header currentUser={currentUser} />
      <div className="container">
        <Component
          currentUser={currentUser}
          {...pageProps}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

AppComponent.getInitialProps = async (appContext: AppContextType) => {
  const client = buildClient(appContext.ctx);
  const { data } = await client.get("/api/users/currentuser");

  let pageProps = {};
  if (appContext.Component.getInitialProps) {
    pageProps = await appContext.Component.getInitialProps(
      appContext.ctx,
      client,
      data.currentUser
    );
  }

  return {
    pageProps,
    ...data,
  };
};

export default AppComponent;
```

the following "client, data.currentUser " is now causing an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error here is that you are typing getInitialProps function explicitly telling it that `appContext` argument is of type `Props1`. `Props1` has shape `{Component: any}` so the only thing you can type safely take from `appContext` is `Component` .. i.e `appContext.Component`, but you are trying to take `appContext.ctx` in first line.

Basically the type are wrong, havent used Next in a while but pretty sure it provides types `NextPageContext`. The types it will pass should be

> AppComponent.getInitialProps = async (appContext: NextPageContext) ...

I dont know if you're expecting extra variables from appContext but as I remember NextJs will just pass the request etc.. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/1467be886a94ac2e66a0442bd6bec1dc53da6608/packages/next/src/shared/lib/utils.ts#L119

So without knowing what `buildClient` needs from the context cant say if you need to restructure code or not, but I dont think you should need anything more than what Next gives in request context. Maybe you meant `const client = buildClient(appContext)`. If buildClient depends on page request can only use properties from `NextPageContext`

**edit**
Didnt read properly Props1 extends NextPageContext, but still ctx is not property on NextPageContext if you look at the types.

Comment: following your recommendation it actually fixed my .ctx & Comment types. 
however it introduced another 2 issues to  about "client, &  data.currentUser"
Now it says   "Expected 1 arguments, but got 3" any idea how to add them please?

Comment: Nice that worked, but Im not sure really what you're trying to do, did you override something in Next context to get Component? Is there a reason you cannot add getInitialProps to the component itself where it is defined? I'm not sure you can do this adding function property https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props#caveats

Comment: basically what I'm trying to do here is pass the client & current user to any Component "Page" that has  getInitialProps. I personally not sure if that's the correct way... "it works fine at the moment." but obviously it's not correct from typescript point of view!